# Improve this TikZ picture

Tags: tikz-pgf

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.geometric} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=1,right]{}(2,0);
\foreach \x in {-3,-2-1,1,2,3}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) ;
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2) -- node[pos=1,above]{}(0,2);
\foreach \t in {-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
\draw[shift={(0,\t)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) ;
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (-1,1)--(1,1)--(1,-1)--(-1,-1)--(-1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=1,right]{}(2,0);
\foreach \x in {-3,-2-1,1,2,3}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) ;
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2) -- node[pos=1,above]{}(0,2);
\foreach \t in {-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
\draw[shift={(0,\t)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) ;
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (0,0) circle (1 cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=1,right]{}(2,0);
\foreach \x in {-3,-2-1,1,2,3}
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) ;
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2) -- node[pos=1,above]{}(0,2);
\foreach \t in {-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
\draw[shift={(0,\t)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) ;
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (0,1)--(1,0)--(0,-1)--(-1,0)--(0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

I want to delete the`-` and add `1` in each edge.

Comment: Unfortunatly your MWE does not compile.

Comment: @samcarter replace `\documentclasse`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if that what is wanted?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{patterns,shapes.geometric} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=1,right]{}(2,0);
%\foreach \x in {-3,-2-1,1,2,3}
%raw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) ;
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{1}(0,2);
%\foreach \t in {-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
%\draw[shift={(0,\t)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) ;
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (-1,1)--(1,1)--(1,-1)--(-1,-1)--(-1,1);
 \node at (0,-2.25){$d_{\infty}$}; % <---------------
\end{tikzpicture}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{1}(2,0); % <----------- modified
%\foreach \x in {-3,-2-1,1,2,3}
%\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) ;
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{1}(0,2); %<-------- modified
%\foreach \t in {-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
%\draw[shift={(0,\t)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) ;
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (0,0) circle (1 cm);
 \node at (0,-2.25){$d_{\infty}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{1}(2,0); % <---------- modified
%\foreach \x in {-3,-2-1,1,2,3}
%\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt) ;
\draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2) -- node[pos=0.75,above right]{1}(0,2); %<------- modified
%\foreach \t in {-3,-2,-1,1,2,3}
%\draw[shift={(0,\t)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt) ;
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (0,1)--(1,0)--(0,-1)--(-1,0)--(0,1);
\node at (0,-2.25){$d_{\infty}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: please how to write under each graph ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou I think it depends of what is to be written? A caption? a pararagraph?

Comment: $d_{\infty}$ that's all

Comment: The best way is to use an tikz node.

Comment: I don't know how to do it ?

Comment: If this solves your problem please accept the answer by clicking the green mark

Answer (score 5):

The little lines are drawn by the for loop in your code. If you don't want them outside of the axis, don't let the loop run from -3 to 3, but only from -2 to 2.

If you also want to remove the lines from the edges of your axis, restrict the loop further to -1 to 1 (or remove them completely, the remaining ticks are not really visible above the edge of the rectangle)

Furthermore there are missing `,`, that is why some of the lines are missing. Also the syntax for syntax for drawing the rectangle (and other geometric shapes, see @marmot's comment below) can be simplified.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns} 

\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[line width=.8pt,->] (-2,0.) -- node[pos=1,right]{}(2,0);
    \foreach \x in {-2,-1,1,2}{
        \draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,2pt) -- (0pt,-2pt);
    }
    \draw[line width=.8pt,->] (0.,-2) -- node[pos=1,above]{}(0,2);
    \foreach \t in {-2,-1,1,2}{
        \draw[shift={(0,\t)},color=black] (2pt,0pt) -- (-2pt,0pt);
    }
    \draw[pattern=north west lines] (-1,-1) rectangle (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot Thanks for your comment! I removed `shapes.geometric` and replaced the custom path with a rectangle. I'll leave the second and third variation of the same code as an exercise for the OP :)